# Dealing with bit streams in C

Tags: c, communication, signal-processing

I am writing some signal processing code in C that has a communications channel. At the output I get a bunch of bits as they arrive.

```
for (n=0; n<BUFFER_LENGTH; n++) {
    /* do some processing that calculates x */
    output[n] = x > 0;
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a good type to represent
   the output array? At first I thought
   uint1_t would be ideal but I hear
   that doesn't necessarily represent
   one bit in memory.
2. Once I find a
   sync pattern in the data I know the
   format of the next bits, how can I
   convert a bunch of 1's and 0's in
   the array into integers, floats,
   doubles, characters, etc.? I've heard of using
   a union but I don't think that will work with an
   array of bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the data in a sufficiently large block of bytes and then iterate through the bits using shifting and masking to extract individual bits sequentially.

e.g. to print out the contents of a buffer as individual bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // uint8_t et al
#include <limits.h> // CHAR_BIT

uint8_t buffer[256];
int b, bit;

for (b = 0; b < 256; ++b)
{
    for (bit = CHAR_BIT - 1; bit >= 0; --bit)
    {
        uint8_t mask = 1 << bit;
        printf("%2d", (buffer[b] & mask) != 0);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to deal with them in multiples of 8 bits and use masking (& operator) and shifting (>> operator) liberally.
So, to take the MP3 bitstream as an example (from http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html):

```
AAAAAAAA AAABBCCD EEEEFFGH IIJJKLMM
```

which can be held in either one 32-bit variable or four 8-bit ones as:

```
MMLKJJII HGFFEEEE DCCBBAAA AAAAAAAA
```

Here you'd have:

```
int i = 0;
while (!syncFound)
{
    uint16 sync = data[i] | ((data[i + 1] & 0x07) << 8);
    if (sync == 0x07ff)
    {
        // The first 11 bits represent a sync.
        uint8 version = (data[i + 1] & 0x18) >> 3;
        uint6 layer = (data[i + 1] & 0x60) >> 5);
        // etc...

        syncFound = TRUE;
    } else {
        // current byte is not the start of a frame. check if the next byte is.
        i++;
    }
```

}

Array bounds checking can get tedious and so too can dealing with variable length headers.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. My situation is a little different. Here you have the `data` array which is already filled with bytes, I'm starting with an array of ones and zeros, eg. `{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}`. But I think the answers so far have shown with shifts and masks I can convert to those to ints, just thought there might be something built in but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a large number of bits in your parsing distance then you have to bit pack.
Think circular buffers to enable continuous operation.
Low bit error rate premise and high entropy data (ie a byte may take all values not just a few symbols) then a union based decoding should be better. Either prep bits with shifts before the union or define eight unions one shift apart and call them as required.

Answer (score -1):

Store them in a large Char buffer and after you get your data you can convert to ints, floats using conversion API's like atoi() atof() etc.
This how its generally done in C socket programming too.

Comment: atoi accepts integer strings right? Like converting the character array "73" to integer value 73. I need to convert {1,0,0,1,0,0,1} to 73. It seems I'll just have to use the shift and bit operators mentioned above and create ints myself.